# Firebase SDK V9 auto-configuration with /__/firebase/init.js

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

After moving to the modular SDK V9 auto-configuration does not work any more using `/__/firebase/init.js`. It's expected as `init.js` contains the old initialization schema.
Unfortunately it is not mentioned neither in the documentation nor in the migration guide how to make auto-configuration work in the V9.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch `/__/firebase/init.json` at runtime but then you have to deal with `initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` being a promise or [top-level await](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_await_top_level) which isn't well supported in tooling yet.

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const response = await fetch('/__/firebase/init.json');
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(await response.json());
```

It's a hack but you could also work around this with `/__/firebase/init.js`.

```html
<script>
  // Capture the config object from /__/firebase/init.js
  window.firebase = {
    initializeApp: (config) => {
      window.firebaseConfig = config;
      // Delete fake Firebase global
      delete window.firebase;
    },
  };
</script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
  
  const firebaseConfig = window.firebaseConfig;

  if (!firebaseConfig) {
    throw new Error('window.firebaseConfig is not defined');
  }

  const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, the V9 SDKs only work with the explicit configuration snippet (which you can get from the Firebase console and from your site's `__/firebase/init.json`).

Unfortunately, since the `__/firebase/init.js` and `__/firebase/init.json` is provided by Firebase Hosting at run-time, it's not really compatible with tree-shaking (which is the primary reason for the modular SDKs).

Comment: If you wanted to, you probably could automate downloading the `__/firebase/init.json` file and including it in your build at run-time

Comment: I've started using `fetch` to request `init.json` on the client side. It seems to be working pretty well so far.